# JS 'return' formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not even sure what to call this problem...I asked around and no one really know how to fix what I suggest. So here I am...

Let me explain what I need done. Working on a JS function. All is well, except this line:

```
return '<div class="pie-label-custom">'+label+'<br/>'+Math.round(series.percent)+'%</div>';
```

Which works. However, I want to remove the return `'<br/>'` - which is easy to do. My problem is, when I do it doesn't add a space. I.e. "nospace" should be "no space".

Question - how do I replace the `<br/>` with a space?

Comment: Maybe a string `' '`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean "no dice"? [Here's a jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxPu2/); it seems to work. If that's not what you want, please explain the problem in more detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

> `<br/>`

use

> `&nbsp;`

Comment: There must be a cleaner solution though, no? &nbsp; are a bit ugly. Esp in JS code